# Problematic vertical alignment using cases and/or aligned environment

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

I'd like for all of my minipages to be aligned at the top, but the `cases` environment is causing a few issues:

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.0075\textwidth}
\raggedright
(a)
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
\raggedright
{$\begin{aligned}[t]
f(x)
&= 6\biggl[1-\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x^2}{2!3^2}-\frac{x^3}{3!3^3}+
\cdots+\frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n!3^n}+\cdots\biggl]\\[0.5em] 
&= 6-2x+\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{x^3}{27}+\cdots+\frac{6(-1)^nx^n}{n!3^n}+\cdots
\end{aligned}$}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\raggedright
$3:\left\{\!\begin{aligned}
1 : & \text{two of}\ 6, -2x, \frac{x^2}{3}, -\frac{x^3}{27}\\
2 : & \text{remaining terms}\\
3 : & \text{general term}\\
\end{aligned}\right.$\newline

$\langle -1\rangle$ missing factor of 6
\end{minipage}

\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

I'd like for the curly brace in the right minipage to be at the same height as the large brackets for the expression contained in the middle minipage. Using either `aligned` (which is what I have above) or `cases` gives me the vertical alignment issue above. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

image of equations is obtain with use of `\raisebox` for last equation and `tabularx` instead of `minipage`s (for slightly shorter code):

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l>{\hsize=0.6\hsize}X
                                 >{\hsize=0.3\hsize}X
                             @{} }
    \hline % remove in real document!
(a) &   $\begin{aligned}[t]
    f(x) & = 6\biggl[1-\frac{x}{3} + \frac{x^2}{2!3^2}-\frac{x^3}{3!3^3}+
            \cdots+\frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n!3^n}+\cdots\biggl]   \\
         &= 6-2x+\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{x^3}{27}+\cdots+\frac{6(-1)^nx^n}{n!3^n}+\cdots
        \end{aligned}$
    &   \raisebox{-0.8\baselineskip}{$3:\begin{cases}
        1 : & \text{two of}\ 6, -2x, \frac{x^2}{3}, -\frac{x^3}{27}\\
        2 : & \text{remaining terms}\\
        3 : & \text{general term}
        \end{cases}$}
        \vspace{1ex}

        $\langle -1\rangle$ missing factor of 6
\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great but could you explain the options you used for `tabularx` here? I realize I'll need to read the package documentation to fully understand but thought you might be able to give me the gist. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow, tabularx` define column type `X` which cells are actually `\parboxe`s (or `minipage`s) with automaticaly determined width. with `\hsize=0.6\hsize` and `\hsize=0.3\hsize` size are determined ratio between last two columns.